# Matching matching anything till '%' not followed by '%' and followed by a set of chars

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group

I would like to match everything until I find a odd number of `%` in sequence that is followed by 2 optional groups and 1 mandatory group. (these groups are similar to C++ `std::printf("%22lld")`)

I'm trying to do this in C++ and I have tried these 2 regexes:

- The first one supports the odd number of '%' but not if the mandatory group is empty:

  ```
  .*?(?=%([0-9.]*)([lhjztL]*)([cCdiouxXeEfgGaAnpsSZRr]))
  ```

  (can capture alone % but not more than 1 %)
- This one is able to handle the odd number of % cases but not if the odd number of %'s mandatory field is empty:

  ```
  ((([^%]*)(?!\s)(?:%{2})*)*%)([0-9.]*)([lhjztL]*)([cCdiouxXeEfgGaAnpsSZRr])
  ```

The version of C++ I'm using doesn't support look-behind but it does support lookahead.

Test string: arg1 %%d arg %22lld, should match
`group1: arg1 %%d arg%`
`group2:22`
`group3:ll`
`group3:d`

Test string: arg % %1586lld asd %d should match
`group1: arg % %1586lld asd %`
`group2:`
`group3:`
`group3:d`

Here are links to what I have tried.

- https://regex101.com/r/pP59oo/2
- https://regex101.com/r/qma7hp/1

Comment: Sorry for the regex syntax, first time posting but the links will show the the corrext syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should fit your needs:

```
/([^\s].*?(?:%(?:%%)*))([0-9.]*)([lhjztL]*)([cCdiouxXeEfgGaAnpsSZRr])/g
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/qma7hp/4)

Comment: Almost! the problem now is that if i want  TestString:arg1 %%%22lld arg2 %22lld, should return 2 matches. Basically what your regex did but stop after finding an match and redo for the next and not find the last thing that matches

Comment: I hope I understood your comment correctly and made an edit to my answer accordingly. It is using the global option now, so it won't return after the first match.